# How to access body data before send of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

Is there a way to access and modify the body data of a XMLHttpRequest before send? I work in Angular and want to modify the request that a third-party library sends. I change the headers like this:

```
beforeSend(e) {
  e.request.setRequestHeader(
    'Authorization',
    'Bearer ' + this.user.tokens.app.accessToken
  );
  e.request.setRequestHeader('tenant-id', this.user.tid);
}
```

Is there any way?

Comment: Assuming the library is an angular library that uses angular's HTTP Client to send the XMLHttpRequest, you can use angular's HTTP interceptors (see https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor for the reference and google for examples). If the library doesn't use angular's HTTP interceptor, then this is more of a vanilla JS question and I think you would have to monkey-patch XMLHttpRequest.send.

Comment: @NicolasB I cannot intercept the request. Do you know any way to patch the request because I am stuck on this problem for quite a while.

Comment: Did you add the interceptor in your module providers?

Comment: Yes I use the interceptor in my app but the requests from the third-party library does not go through it because it handles its own requests. You can only modify the requests using events (in my case beforeSend)

Comment: @gg123 Assuming you can't use HTTPInterceptors, you'd do something like `const oldXmlHTTPRequestSend = XMLHttpRequest.send;` and then `XMLHttpRequest.send = (...args) => { beforeSend(...args); oldXmlHttpRequestSend(...args); }`

Comment: I still strongly believe that you can intercept the third-party requests using HTTPInterceptors

Comment: At the end it was more simple to add the property to the header.